# Benefits of using $scope.foo versus foo.vaue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In a controller, we can sometimes access inputs values by the value of their DOM id instead of setting an ng-model directive and then binding the DOM value to $scope.

For example, in

```
<input type="text" ng-model="foo" id=foo>
```

we can either use `$scope.foo` or `foo.value` in the controller. What is the advantage of using $scope in this case?

Comment: what do you mean by foo.value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the main benefits of using `ng-model` instead of getting the value of input by id is **two-way binding**. Your variable from `ng-model` is always up to date and you can use it directly in html or wherever you want.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="foo" id="fooInput" />
<p>ng-model value: <span ng-bind="foo"></span></p>
```

If you choose approach when you get value from input by id you will lose this feature, but you get a little bit better performance. Because whenever you type into into, it will trigger a `$digest` cycle causing Angular to update all watchers and bindings in the app to see if anything has changed.

A little demo on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NwtWm41xNu4pz8ly7CYQ?p=preview).